# Creating a command equivalent to a \kern, for glosses

Tags: macros, gb4e, linguex

I am using `gb4e` for glosses inside the `linguex` environment.

In order to identify word-units, we have to input a space, not only after each unit we want to gloss on its own, but also after the corresponding gloss.

For example if I want to write *l'école* and am planning to input the gloss 'the school', I have to type `l' école`.

But obviously, you don't always want a *real* space to be typeset: in some cases, i.e. when the counterpart is smaller, this will just give you an undesirable extra space. For example:

```
\gll lorsqu' il est venu\\
     when he came\\
```

will give you a space between *lorsqu'* and *il* (cf. 1a on the picture), which obviously we don't want.

In order to suppress the space, I use `\kern0.01em`  **(note the space after the command)**, which works very nicely: the space is taken into consideration by the engine for word segmentation, **but is not actually typeset**; see (2a–b).

However, when I have many delimitations to input, I would prefer to use a simple command, let's say `\sep`, which would be equivalent to `\kern0.01em` .

But, for reasons that we all know, the space after `\sep` won't be taken into consideration; see (3).

Now if I try `\sep{}` , it is no better, since the space is taken into consideration, but **as a *real* space**; see (4).

How do you think I should proceed?

**EDIT**
`wipet` suggested \def\sep#1{kern0.01em} which works if passing the command with empty delimiters, i.e. `\sep{}`. The question is, thus, solved.

In a subsidiary way, however, it could be even more convenient to find an approach which would *not* require the empty braces.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}

\newcommand{\sep}{\kern0.01em}

\begin{document}

\ex.
    \a. \gll    lorsqu' il est~venu\\
                when he came\\
    \b. \gll    un trompe- la- mort\\
                a deceives- the- death\\
% I do not want extra spaces. Spaces are only typed as word boundaries.
            
                    
\ex.
    \a. \gll    lorsqu'\kern0.01em il est~venu\\
                when he came\\
    \b. \gll    un trompe- la- mort\\
                a deceives-\kern0.01em the-\kern0.01em death\\
% This is what I want: the space after the kern is only regarded as a word boundary, not actually typeset.
            
            
\ex.
    \a. \gll    lorsqu'\sep il est~venu\\
                when he came\\
    \b. \gll    un trompe- la- mort\\
                a deceives-\sep the-\sep death\\ % The space is ignored.

\ex.
    \a. \gll    lorsqu'\sep{} il est~venu\\
                when he came\\
    \b. \gll    un trompe- la- mort\\
                a deceives-\sep{} the-\sep{} death\\
% The space is regarded as a true space: back to the original problem.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I understand that this breaks the standard conventions of French orthography, but the fact that “l’école” is written without spaces doesn't change the fact that ”l’” and “école” are distinct functional units that the gloss should separate.

Comment: Of course *l'* and *école* will be separated since *the* is bigger than *l'*; I said "in some cases", such as *lorsqu'il/when*. To make it clearer, I edited the post, adding "you don't *always* want a real space".

Comment: Isn't the word-unit defined as space-separated text, so that `l'école` glosses as `the.FEM.SING.-school`?

Comment: Yes this is a good system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to define

```
\def\sep#1{\kern0.01em}
```

and use `\sep{}` The `#1` parameter is empty in this case and the TeX primitive `\kern` inserts desired kern and ignores the space after "em" unit, i.e the space after `\sep{}`.

If you don't want to write `{}`, you can define

```
\def\sep/{\kern0.01em}
```

and use `\sep/` with the same result as above.

Comment: Any alternative which would avoid the recourse to {} ?

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the delay, I just hadn't seen your edit :/